# Apollo graphql common type conflict

Tags: graphql, apollo-client

I started using schema stitching and while types are not conflicting everything is working.

But I am now merging three schema and I have PageInfo and Edge on local schema and another remote schema. Types Edge and PageInfo are completely different on both and I just need to use local PageInfo and Edge on local schema and remote on remote.

already tried all 3 examples of schema stitching for resolve type conflict but nothing helps.

https://www.advancedgraphql.com/content/schema-stitching/ex1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are (many different) known problems with schema stitching and you are currently having one of them. Apollo has deprecated schema stitching and released [Federation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/federation/introduction/) recently to replace it.
Turns out that stitching is a lot of work and it becomes much less difficult if the APIs underneath are aware that they are contributing to a single schema.

If you are stitching together APIs that you don't control you will need a different solution. The simples solution could be to use something like [GraphQL Binding](https://github.com/graphql-binding/graphql-binding) and replicate the desired parts in your schema and then delegate to the API below. This has the advantage that *your* schema does not randomly change or break at runtime when the third party API changes. There are also a lot of tools that allow for example importing types into your schema file from an external schema file.